# TouchMove events stopped working in chrome 72 and latest webkit

Tags: android, google-chrome, webkit, desktop, touchmove

In recent Chrome (Desktop) and Webkit (Android) update touchmove events stopped working. The bug is very finicky, for example it only breaks if I draw something in canvas and canvas height is at least 220px. If height is 219px or if I don't draw on canvas it works. Also if canvas has 1px border or outline it works, if it has 0px border or outline it doesn't work.

It's hard to test in fiddle so I put it on separate page: https://ghost.sk/chrome-touchmove-error/

If you want to test it in chrome go to console (Ctrl+Shift+I) and turn on mobile mode (Ctrl+Shift+M). When you touch and move over image witout border it doesn't work. If you touch and move over image with border it works. Here on this video is what it does: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVnYU45MzGU (first two are chrome 72, second two is chromium 71) and here is latest webkit version https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0QIRR-bKLo

Comment: Suffering this too. Thanks for the border tip, adding a 1px border to patch things at the moment.

Comment: I had the same issue / or similar. Solved it by having my canvas in a modal window and disabled all background content temporarily.